# How to disable HockeyApp updates on iOS

Tags: ios, software-update

Have an app on two test phones (Android & iOS) which is still in beta testing and distributed via HockeyApp. Got an update on the Android and noticed the developer has removed some important core functionality (on purpose), so I'd like my iOS device not to be updated. I haven't lunched the app on the iOS device since the update happened to avoid it but really need access this functionality one more time so I can take some notes before allowing to update. I'm sure once I lunch it it'll immediately update since the update seems to be mandatory, that's what happened in the Android. I'm trying to find a way to block it from checking for updates, any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried going into Airplane mode before you open the app?  If the update wasn't pushed to your device already, then not having network/cell access could stop it from updating.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, I tried that but the app needs to retrieve info online also in order to work.  That's why I was expecting to find a way to block something like a series of IPs or similar.

Comment: Can you ask the developer for a build that allows you to do what you want?  If it's a beta app then you have to expect to lose your info on updates or changes made by the developer.

Comment: Thanks fsb.. yeah I understand that, actually the developer removed the feature on purpose and forced the update since he doesn't anyone to have it.  This is an app that doesn't meet guidelines to be published in the appstore so it is sold as beta on the side with the understanding that such changes could occur and not longer be supported.  I was just hopping there was another way of blocking the update to happen but there seems to be no easy solution for that.  I have searched the net for like a week already before trying to post forums for a solution.

Comment: Yea, I saw some of your other posts were put on hold.  I hope you find someone that knows the answer!